# Custom YoloV4 Detection Time

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I have trained a custom YoloV4, single class object detector using [AlexeyAB's darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet).

The best weight files of my model result in the following performance

[image: metrics of my model trained on google colab]

I obtained this evaluation using the command,

```
darknet.exe detector map data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg backup\yolo-custom-best.weights
```

Upon running the model on a video, I get around 25 fps.

**My Question is** : When I read articles about YOLO, they claim that it detects in milliseconds (ms). Why is my model showing detection time of 5 seconds but comparable in FPS to other, much faster models?

- Is the detection time shown in the image (returned by the given command), something different?
  (If yes, then how do I find how fast my model is?)
- If No, how to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the detection time mentioned in the paper, which is the same as the one mentioned in the GitHub repo [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4096485/112776361-281d8380-9048-11eb-8083-8728b12dcd55.png) is assuming it's run on a **`single batch`** at test time on a **`Tesla V100`** GPU. In addition to these factors, the runtime also varies according to the size of the input image

In case you are using a different GPU or the CPU, it shouldn't be surprising for you to find longer detection times. The same goes with the FPS

Comment: So I ran a detection with my model, and there too the time gets mentioned with detection, it's around 30ms. So, I guess this time is of something different, though it says detection time.